# Error during docker compose: build path either does not exist, is not accessible, or is not a valid URL

Tags: docker, docker-compose

phpstorm swears at parsing the `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
Error while parsing "/home/victor/PhpstormProjects/cpalife-back/docker-compose.yml"
Process `docker-compose config` failed. build path /home/victor/PhpstormProjects/tickets/docker/php-fpm either does not exist, is not accessible, or is not a valid URL.
```

```
version: '3.4'

networks:
  ppticket:
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.46.0.0/16

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.14.0-alpine
    container_name: tt_nginx
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    networks:
      ppticket:
        ipv4_address: 172.46.0.2
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./docker/logs/nginx:/var/log/nginx
      - ./docker/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ./docker/nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/config.template:ro
    environment:
      NGINX_HOST: ${BASE_DOMAIN}
    cap_add:
      - SYS_TIME
    command: /bin/sh -c "envsubst '$$NGINX_HOST' < /etc/nginx/conf.d/config.template > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf && nginx -g 'daemon off;'"

  #PHP
  php:
    build: ./docker/php
    container_name: cpa_php
    expose:
      - 9000
    networks:
      ppticket:
        ipv4_address: 172.46.0.3
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./docker/logs/php:/var/log/php
      - ./docker/php/php.ini:/etc/php/php.ini:ro
      - ./docker/php/www.conf:/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf:ro
    environment:
      XDEBUG_CONFIG: "remote_host=172.46.0.0 remote_enable=1"
      PHP_IDE_CONFIG: "serverName=Docker"
    cap_add:
      - SYS_TIME
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    restart: always
  #MYSQL
  mysql:
    image: percona:5.7.23
    container_name: cpa_mysql
    volumes:
      - ./docker/data/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./docker/logs/mysql:/var/log/mysql
    networks:
      ppticket:
        ipv4_address: 172.46.0.4
    expose:
      - 3306
    ports:
      - 127.0.0.1:3306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DB}
      MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
    cap_add:
      - SYS_TIME
    restart: always
    command: "mysqld --collation-server=utf8_general_ci --character-set-server=utf8 --max_allowed_packet=3M"
```

Comment: I use Docker for Windows Desktop Community and had the same issue after updating to 2.1.0.3 (38240). I don't know the origin or a reasonable solution, but after manually changing and setting the whitespaces in the file, it somehow worked again and even did so, after I reverted my changes.

Comment: Make sure whether you deleted the folder of file by mistake. In my case I supposed to delete the data/ folder and I ended up deleting the containers/ folder.

Answer (score 10):

This problem occours when the directory of the docker-compose.yml is different from the directory of  the docker file.

1. Make sure the path given in doker-compose.yml  is inside the same directory

if you are on linux based system check the path  by " pwd"

move the directory

"mv /path/to/source /path/to/dest"

Answer (score 7):

I build docker images on windows. To solve the issue you will use the Dockerfile specified in the build path of your Docker-compose.yml. So check the directory of your Dockerfile. Hope this helps
[image]

Answer (score 0):

For me this error was on **WSL 2**.

So for **WSL or WSL 2 (Windows Subsystem for Linux)**, I resolved it as

As stated on docker docs

> 1. Follow the usual installation instructions to install Docker Desktop.
>    If you are running a supported system, Docker Desktop prompts you to
>    enable WSL 2 during installation. Read the information displayed on
>    the screen and enable WSL 2 to continue.
> 2. Start Docker Desktop from the Windows Start menu.
> 3. From the Docker menu, select **Settings > General**.
> 4. Select the Use WSL 2 based engine check box. If you have installed Docker Desktop on a system that supports WSL 2,
>    this option will be enabled by default.
> 5. Click **Apply & Restart**.
> 6. Ensure the distribution runs in WSL 2 mode. WSL can run distributions in both v1 or v2 mode.
>
> To check the WSL mode, run:
>
> `wsl.exe -l -v`
>
> To upgrade your existing Linux distro to v2, run:
>
> `wsl.exe --set-version (distro name) 2`
>
> To set v2 as the default version for future installations, run:
>
> `wsl.exe --set-default-version 2`
>
> When Docker Desktop restarts, go to Settings > Resources > WSL
> Integration.
>
> The Docker-WSL integration will be enabled on your default WSL
> distribution. To change your default WSL distro, run `wsl --set-default <distro name>.`
>
> For example, to set Ubuntu as your default WSL distro, run
>
> `wsl --set-default ubuntu.`
>
> Optionally, select any additional distributions you would like to
> enable the Docker-WSL integration on.

[Docker Desktop WSL 2 backend](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/windows/wsl/)